# Using CSS to stop an item moving depending on screen size - Wordpress/Divi

Tags: css, wordpress, overlay, divi

I am trying to custom code a close button for a Divi Overlay on our Wordpress site.
I can position the button fine, but when I resize the window or view it on a tablet, the button moves. I've tried using Position: relative / fixed / absolute but none of that seemed to work.

For context - this code is within a code module in the Divi builder, which sits in a row, within a section.

Here is the code for the button;

```
<pee><a class="close-divi-overlay" href="#close">×</a></pee>

<style>
a.close-divi-overlay {
/* a) Control the position of the close button*/
right: 450px!important;
top: 150px !important;
z-index: 10010 !important;
display: block !important;
position: absolute !important;
/* b) Size of the close button - Adjust if is necessary*/
width: 46px !important;
height: 48px !important;
font-size: 28px !important;
line-height: 48px !important;
/* c) Background and border of the close button*/
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff !important;
border: solid 0px #fff !important;
border-radius: 50% !important;
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #888 !important;
/* d) Font styles*/
color: #0B3E5C !important;
font-family: !monospace !important;
font-weight: bold !important;
text-align: center !important;
text-decoration: none !important;
  }
</style>
```

So is there a way to position this button so that it doesn't move when the window is resized?

Comment: First thing I noticed, you are not using responsive units for top and right properties. You might try "vh" (viewport height) and "vw" (viewport width) for positioning. And remember, position absolute takes the element out of the normal flow, collapses the space it consumed before, and uses top, bottom, left, right for positioning (most of the time relative to the window)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, much appreciated! I'm not an expert in CSS by any means - so are you saying I shouldn't be using position: absolute? What position tag should I use instead?

Comment: Alright, it would be great if you could share more information: 1. Where do you want to place the button (maybe screenshot) 2. Styles of the parent element